# add_rewrite_rule not working for language specific characters

Tags: url-rewriting, search, urls, rewrite-rules, encoding

My default search query:

```
example.com/search/?search_text=keyword
```

What I want to transform it:

```
example.com/search/keyword
```

So I added this to my `function.php`

```
add_rewrite_rule('^search/([^/]*)?','index.php?pagename=search&search_text=$matches[1]','top');
```

Works fine for english alphabet but whenever I search a keyword in my language like this:

```
example.com/search/kırmızı
```

The title of the page becomes: `k%C4%B1rm%C4%B1z%C4%B1` and no results returned.

Let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening due to encoding. I assume you have a function in your search page, which you get and use `search_text` inside that template. You should decode the URL before doing so.

The [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) function would be what you are looking for. Your string is also UTF-8 encoded, so this is what you are going to need:

```
$string = utf8_decode( urldecode( $_GET['search_text'] ) );
```

Now you can use the decoded string in your search.

Comment: Your response showed me the way, I don't take `search_text` from `$_GET`, but using `get_query_var`. So the following alone worked for me: `urldecode( get_query_var('search_text') ) ;`

Comment: I didn't have access to your code, so that was a total guess. Glad to see you've found the cure for the problem :)